ubuntu 24.04 drops traffic redirected from router
I have almost zero experience in Linux. What should I do to stop Ubuntu from dropping traffic that is redirected to it from the router, which comes from the external network? Port forwarding is enabled on the router. In Wireshark, I see that a SYN packet is coming.
I have already tried everything. In ufw, I allowed all ports, allowed incoming traffic, manually edited files, where there was DROP or REJECT, entered ACCEPT, allowed traffic forwarding, nothing gave a result. I am already starting to think that this is how Linux is designed, and this cannot be changed at all.
I need this for a proxy (3x-ui), which is not on a VPS, but at my home.
I need it to work like this:
mobile phone (V2rayNG) -> my router with a public ip (a rule with port forwarding has been created) -> ubuntu (3x-ui) -> a wireguard connection running in ubuntu.


Do you have ports open on port 15000?  Do you have something running on port 15000 to handle the requests?

Yes, the port is open in ufw. Initially, ufw was disabled.
I tried adding only the port I needed and all ports, no difference.
The port is listened to by the 3x-ui panel.
But it works if I do it this way: traffic from the router is first redirected to a computer with windows, where the 3proxy program is running, which then redirects the traffic to ubuntu.
This works both when ufw is enabled and when it is disabled. In this case, ubuntu thinks that the traffic came from the local network, and not from the external network, and therefore does not drop traffic.

It seems that it is impossible to make Ubuntu not drop packets redirected from the router that come from the Internet. Too bad. Even a simple connection via RDP/XRDP does not work when trying to connect from an external network. Of course, it works in the local network.
For now, I have made a proxy on one machine: I installed Windows, and in it a virtual Ubuntu. In the future, I will divide it into 2 different machines.
